# Как найти сумму элементов многомерного (произвольного) массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Дан такой массив `let arr = [[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]], [8, [9, 10]]];`
Я насчитал три вложенности поэтому моё решение такое:

```js
let arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]],
  [8, [9, 10]]
];
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  sum += arr[i];
  for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    sum += arr[i][j];
    for (let k = 0; k < arr[i][j].length; k++) {
      sum += arr[i][j][k];
    }

  }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Но что-то не так!Сумма получается бешеной. Подскажите мою ошибку и как было бы правильно? Как решать подобные задачи?

Comment: проблема в том, что ты складываешь число с массивом. Проверяй перед сложение число это или массив и все

Comment: Попробовать https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat  ??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы посчитать сумму элементов массива произвольной вложенности, удобней сначала превратить его в плоский массив без всякой вложенности, а потом уже считать сумму его элементов.

Ваша же ошибка в том, что перед тем, как прибавить к сумме значение элемента массива, вы не проверяете, является ли оно действительно числом.

```js
let arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]],
  [8, [9, 10]]
];
let sum = 0;

arr = arr.flat(Infinity)

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     sum += arr[i];
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к выше указаному коду смею предложить свой вариант в более декларативном функциональном стиле

```
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]],
  [8, [9, 10]]
];

const sum = arr.flat(Infinity).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема в том, что идет складывание числовых значение и вложенных массивов.

Для решения достаточно добавить проверку, что элемент является массивом, и в этом случае складывать его элементы.

Это хорошо выражается с помощью рекурсии

```js
let arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]],
  [8, [9, 10]]
];

console.log(sum(arr));

function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + (Array.isArray(cur) ? sum(cur) : cur), 0)
}
```

Также, можно обойтись и без рекурсии:

```js
let arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]],
  [8, [9, 10]]
];

let sum = 0;
while (arr.length) {
  var cur = arr.shift();
  if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
    arr.unshift(...cur);
    continue;
  }

  sum += cur;
}

console.log(sum);
```